# Where to place internal functions of angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style

AngularJS code style question.
I have an Angular module:

```
angular.module('module', [])
    .controller('ModuleCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var fnc = MenuControllerFunctions;
        $scope.onBtnPressed = fnc.handlerFnc();
    })
;
var MenuControllerFunctions = {
    handlerFnc: function(){
        return function() {
            console.log('Button pressed')
        }
    }
};
```

Where should i place handlerFnc function?
In external variable (like here) or somewhere else?
Is any way to place it in module but not in '.controller' section?

Comment: If you want to reuse `MenuControllerFunctions` throughout your angular app you could use it as a service or factory. If you want to keep your method private then just contain it within the context of the controller's anonymous function definition?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , you have to do like this

```
angular.module('module', [])
.controller('MenuController', MenuController);

 MenuController.$inject(['$scope']);

 function MenuController ($scope) {
      $scope.onBtnPressed = handlerFnc;

     function handlerFnc(){
         console.log('Button pressed')
    }
};
```